# .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `boost::python::import(boost::python::str)'

Tags: python, c++, ubuntu, boost, caffe

I get this error with Python2.7 and Ubuntu15.10:

```
jalal@klein:~/computer_vision/py-faster-rcnn/caffe-fast-rcnn$ make -j8 && make pycaffe

CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin
CXX/LD -o .build_release/examples/cpp_classification/classification.bin
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_system.so.1.58.0, needed by .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so, may conflict with libboost_system.so.1.61.0
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libboost_thread.so.1.58.0, needed by .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so, may conflict with libboost_thread.so.1.61.0
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `boost::python::throw_error_already_set()'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `boost::python::import(boost::python::str)'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyEval_CallFunction'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `typeinfo for boost::python::error_already_set'
.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_Print'
```

How can I fix this?
I have boost installed.
From https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn

I already have run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential g++ python-dev autotools-dev libicu-dev build-essential libbz2-dev libboost-all-dev
```

And:

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-python-dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Boost from the source worked for me!
After downloading the Boost source code from its official website:

```
sudo ./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
./b2
sudo ./b2 install
```